# Getting error "No rule to make target `certs', needed by `rehash.time'. Stop."

Tags: android, android-ndk, openssl, makefile

I am trying to compile Openssl1.0.1g. But facing the below mentioned error.

```
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/test/openssl-1.0.1g/apps'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/test/openssl-1.0.1g/apps'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/test/openssl-1.0.1g'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `certs', needed by `rehash.time'.  Stop.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/test/openssl-1.0.1g'
make[1]: *** [openssl] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/test/openssl-1.0.1g/apps'
make: *** [build_apps] Error 1
```

But when I was compiling Openssl1.0.1f, I was not facing any issue like this. I compared both make files after configure. There is no change.

Please let me know if anyone faced this issue and has resolved the same.

Thanks.

Comment: Temporary solution: Do make again with out make clean. Creating ".so" files.

Comment: You need to provide the host system, and how you configured OpenSSL. What are your values for `MACHINE`, `SYSTEM`, `ARCH`, `CROSS_COMPILE`, `ANDROID_DEV` and `HOSTCC`? If you follow OpenSSL's instructions (rather than someone's blog), then you won't have these troubles. You can find OpenSSL's instructions at [OpenSSL and Android](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Android).